# Problem with Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7 RC1

Tags: visual-studio, beta

Has anyone run into the error where your upgrading a VS2008 project which targets .NET 3.5 to VS2010 and the error message states that you don't have .NEt 3.5 installed?

Snippet from the error message below

"is targeting ".NETFramework, Version=v3.5, Profile=Full", which is not installed on this machine"

I know that running multiple unreleased products together increases my changes for failure, but I would still like to try.

Comment: Does it work if you create a new .NET 3.5 project?  I've actually got a Windows 7 RC1 install going right this minute which is slated for a VS2K10 install this afternoon.  I'll scrap it if it doesn't work.

Comment: Good question, and YES, a new project seems to work. ( I tried a c# winforms project targeted to .NET 3.5 as my test. )

Comment: This sounds like an issue for MSDN Connect rather than a programming question.

Comment: I'm reluctant to forcibly close this (it is on topic), but I expect that bzlm is right: for beta-1 software the MSDN/connect route is probably more appropriate.

Comment: I am perusing that as well, but I submitted it here as well in the interested of expedience. ( Connect is a bit slow ).

That said, if I don't get any solutions to this in a day or so, I'll answer the question with a link to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at this time, this error appears to be a bug in VSTS2010.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=453802

Please vote for the bug in MS Connect if you have this problem as well.